# how to speed up the computation of the sparse matrix in python

Tags: python, scipy

Recently, i have the problem of speeding up the computation of the sparse matrix in python. Now, the dimension of the W is [17000, 2] and b is [1,2]. And when others use the web service i will compute the xW + b, where the dimension of the x is [1, 17000]. But what confuse me is when i do the pressure test with ab command, if the Concurrency is lower than 100 per second, then it can operate it with 0.002 ms, but if Concurrency pass that limit, the cost time will fly to 4 ms, i want to know what happen in this procedure.

P.S. all the relevant matrices are sparse matrices

Comment: Sparse matrix multiplication, `x*W` uses a mix of Python and compiled (cython) code.  I don't know why it should be any more susceptible to problems like this than common `numpy` (dense) array operations.

Comment: i finally used the scipy.sparse.csr_matrix.dot to compute instead of using x*W directly, i am afraid that it will do the operation like todense() or toarray() in the precedure. And i also used other pressure test software(Jmeter), the problem disappeared.